# Cassandra server crashing on windows 7

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver

I have installed Datastax Cassandra community Server 2.2.3 on windows 7. It was working well a moment ago, after restarting my machine the Cassandra server crashed. I can't even open the cql shell command line. 
The error message that I get is:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042]
```

**The error message which is found in the system.log is**

```
INFO  [SharedPool-Worker-2] 2016-01-18 09:43:22,141 Message.java:605 - Unexpected exception during request; channel = [id: 0xafffeedf, /127.0.0.1:53095 :> 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9042]
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:311) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:225) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_72]
WARN  [SharedPool-Worker-4] 2016-01-18 09:43:48,833 NoSpamLogger.java:94 - Unlogged batch covering 3 partitions detected against tables [acasystem.Job, acasystem._75fd0052d53648dabb4f8e74b69cbaa9_inverse, acasystem._5d3f48c729c54dad939d5597b1d041ea_inverse]. You should use a logged batch for atomicity, or asynchronous writes for performance.
```

---

Comment: Might be a network/firewall problem. Can you provide the number of nodes, what happens when server is restarted, etc.
does the same error happens again when the server is restarted?